# python code to add jobs to crontab not working

Tags: python, cron

**I have written a small python script to automate the process of adding jobs to crontab but the job added via the script is not working and same job  when given manually working fine**

*HERE IS THE CODE:*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def scheduler(time=["*","*","*","*","*"],message="no message set"):
 crontab_pointer=open('/var/spool/cron/crontabs/sky','a')
 schedule_string="\n"+" ".join(time)+" "+message+"\n"
 crontab_pointer.write(schedule_string)
 crontab_pointer.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
 scheduler(time=["52","18","*","*","*"],message="env DISPLAY=:0 /home/sky/scripts/notify2.sh")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Permissions

Make sure the user you're running your python script as root.  I did some quick testing and other users can't access their /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$username files.  This is by design if I can remember correctly.  You're supposed to use the `crontab -e` command to edit your crontab.

`sudo python editcron.py`

Really, the Python you've written isn't exactly wrong.  It opens the file, adds the string, then closes it.  Nothing ground-breaking here.  I just added some file system checks in to make sure you can get to that file.

## Code

```
import os

def scheduler(time=['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], message='no message set', username='sky'):
    crontab_fn = '/var/spool/cron/crontabs/{!s}'.format(username)
    if not os.path.exists(crontab_fn):
        raise StandardError("File {} missing".format(crontab_fn))
    if not os.access(crontab_fn, os.W_OK):
        raise StandardError("Cannot write to file, run as root")
    crontab_fh = open(crontab_fn, 'a')
    schedule_string = "\n{t:s} {m:s}\n".format(
        t=' '.join(time),
        m=message
    )
    crontab_fh.write(schedule_string)
    crontab_fh.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    time = ["52","18","*","*","*"]
    message = "env DISPLAY=:0 /home/sky/scripts/notify2.sh"
    scheduler(time, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTES** from man cron:
>          cron searches its spool area (/var/spool/cron/crontabs) for crontab files (which are named after  accounts  in
>          /etc/passwd);  crontabs  found  are  loaded  into  memory.  Note that crontabs in **this directory should not be
>          accessed directly** - the **crontab command** should be used to access and update them.

---

> **Question**: ... same job when given manually working fine

I assume you use `crontab <filename>` here!

---

Search for a `python module` or use `module subprocess.run(...)` to start `crontab <filename>` from within your **.py**.

[using-the-subprocess-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.